# Portable SQL Server

Tags: .net, sql-server, windows, windows-xp

I need to install SQL Server, however I have a BIG problem with it. I remember when I tried to install it I got error with MSXML and it was not installed because of MSXML and some other component. Is there any portable version of SQL Server?

Comment: Have you looked into SQLLite?

Comment: you could use SQL CE or SQL Express, it all depends on what are your needs for SQL?

Comment: Way off topic?  SQLLite is a flat file and a driver, if your looking for portable its pretty good.

Comment: I NEED SQL SERVER!

Comment: Please don't yell, friend.

Comment: What version of Windows, including SP are you using?

Comment: Am I the only one thinking **"I NEED SQL SERVER!"** is going to become an instant meme? :-D

Answer (score 7):

SQL Compact Edition:

- http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2005/en/us/compact.aspx

Answer (score 4):

There is no such thing as a "portable" version of Sql Server, as provided by Microsoft. There are "light" versions of Sql Server such as [Sql Server Compact edition](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlservercompact/archive/2011/01/12/microsoft-sql-server-compact-4-0-is-available-for-download.aspx), but any "portable" version would have to be created by you.

By "created by you" I mean:

- Extracting all the files from the installers
- Determining how/where they need to be deployed/registered
- Understanding what configuration needs to be written in lieu of the installer doing so
- Capturing any dependencies that are non-core-OS (such as MSXML, if the OS being targeted is absent of the required version) and doing all the previous steps for them as well.
- Putting together a process/script to deploy everything listed above.

In other words, you'd need to write the Sql Server installer.

**Find and resolve the issue around MSXML (try http://www.serverfault.com), that's the real way to solve this issue**

Answer (score 2):

You can fix the MSXML related errors while installing SQL Server 2005 with MSXML_FIX.VBS found [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/968749).

Comment: i will try that, thx

Answer (score 1):

It would be ***quite*** useful to know which version of Windows are you working with, and which version of SQL Server your application requires.

"Light" versions of SQL Server have been around for a while, starting with MSDE (for SQL Server 7.0 and 2000) and ending with SQL Server Express and/or Compact for more current releases; but no one of them is going to install properly if you have issues with required components such as MSXML, so you really should first look into fixing them.

Answer (score 0):

[Microsoft SQL Server Compact 4.0](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=033CFB76-5382-44FB-BC7E-B3C8174832E2) :

> Microsoft SQL Server Compact 4.0 is a
>   free, embedded database that software
>   developers can use for building
>   ASP.NET websites and Windows desktop
>   applications